# MS Access 2007 login form

Tags: database

I am working with a database in Access, and I am creating a login form to restrict data with a password:

- anyone who has the password can access the database
- if a wrong password is entered no database access is granted
- after three unsuccessful logins, automatically close the database.

I tried some code , but I don't know why it doesn't work. A part of the code it this:

```
      Private Sub btn_login_Click()
      UserName.SetFocus
      If UserName = "admin" And password = "test" Then
      MsgBox "Password correct", vbInformation, "CD shop"
      MsgBox "welcome", vbInformation, "cdshop"
      DoCmd.Close
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard"
      ElseIf UserName = "menager" And password = "menager" Then
      MsgBox "password correct", vbInformation, "cd shop"
      MsgBox "password correct", vbInformation, "cd shop"
      MsgBox "welcome", vbInformation, "cd shop"
      DoCmd.Close
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard"
      Else
      MsgBox "Please write your username and password correct"
      End If
      End Sub
      DoCmd.Close
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard"
      Else
      MsgBox "Please write your username and password correct"
      End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: I am unable to tell what you are asking. Your "question" doesn't contain any questions. I would recommend reading the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions and re-asking your question.

Comment: richard i edited my question